# Issue with Beep in CaptureSDK's SocketCamController

Tags: ios, swift, dart, beep, capture-sdk

**Issue Description:**
I have encountered an issue in the CaptureSDK for Flutter. There is a strange beep coming from the SocketCamController. However, there is no SocketCamController found in our project's codebase. I've tried to troubleshoot and resolve this error, but I haven't been able to find a specific solution to address it.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- [ ] Import CaptureSDK in a Flutter project.
- [ ] Use Capture methods and  not use the SocketCamController.
- [ ] Observe the unexpected SocketCamController - SocketCamController.swift:520: Beep found in CaptureSDK

**Behavior:**
When I open Device arrival then after not able to close. When I connect Bluetooth connection at first time it work perfect and again I try to do same thing twice then it will be produce beep found in Capture SDK error, I’ve tried to troubleshoot many times with objective c files for produce the error but not found any solutions yet, Please look into below mentioned files for iOS Capture_SDK_flutters that I have tried for troubleshoot

- [ ] CaptureFlutterHandle.h
- [ ] CaptureFlutterHandle.m
- [ ] CaptureFlutterPlugin.h
- [ ] CaptureFlutterPlugin.m
- [ ] IosTransport.h
- [ ] IosTransport.m
- [ ] TransportConnector.h
- [ ] TransportConnector.m

**Additional Information:**

- Flutter Version: [Flutter 3.3.10]
- CaptureSDK Version: [capturesdk_flutter: 1.3.1]
- Device/Emulator: [All Device]

[[provided my error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTctg.png)]

I have thoroughly checked our project's codebase, and there is no reference or usage of SocketCamController. This issue seems to be originating from the CaptureSDK itself. Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.